# SqlCeExpression was caught, error paring the query

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-ce

Im trying to insert data to my compact database, I got this error:

```
There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 1,Token in error = USE ]
```

And here is my code, mostly found online:

```
                SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\CompactDatabase.sdf");
                conn.Open();

                SqlCeCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = "USE Movie INSERT INTO Movie(title, ean) VALUES(?,?)";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@title", title);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ean", ean);
                cmd.Prepare();                
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Anyone figure out the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Anyone figure out the problem?

Just throw away `USE` clause and execute this query instead:

```
INSERT INTO Movie(title, ean) VALUES(?,?)
```

`USE` is a context switching clause between databases in T-SQL, that is not applicable here.

Answer (score 0):

You commandtext is wrong about parameterized side. Try with `@title` and `@ean` not `?,?`. Like this;

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Movie(title, ean) VALUES(@title, @ean)";
```

Delete `USE Movie` part also.

Check out [`C# SqlParameter`](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter) which is great article.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
USE Movie; INSERT INTO Movie(title, ean) VALUES(?,?)
```

Note the `;` IIRC, this is the same as `GO` in SQL proper.